# How to write bold and italics with \usepackage[cm]{sfmath}?

Tags: math-mode, bold, italic

How to write bold and italics \usepackage[cm]{sfmath} provided?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,hidelinks]{report}
       
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}

\newcommand{\pinom}{\hbox{$\mathcal{\pi}$}}

\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{bm}  
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& \pinom = P (\vb*{\Theta}_\mathrm{M} | M \vb*{D}) \\ 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The desired result is to get D and theta in italics.

Comment: please fix your example so that it shows the problem that you are having, as posted it produces no output at all.  Note that `bm` should always be loaded after any other font packages, and you are loading it first.

Comment: I am sorry. I copied it wrong. I tried to set bm later, but it did not help.

Comment: what is the intention of `\newcommand{\pinom}{\hbox{$\mathcal{\pi}$}}`  ? I don't know any font set that has anything the could be called calligraphic Greek? Just use `\newcommand{\pinom}{\pi}`  to get an italic D you could just type D

Comment: \pinom is in a different font than just \pi, but it is not important. I know that I get an italic D by typing D, but how to get bold and simultaneously italics D? The same I would like for theta.

Comment: bm can only access bold fonts that are available. the sfmath package you are using documents the cm option with   % \sfdefault is cmss
  % no slanted bold letters
  % no slanted bold capital Greeks

Comment: `\pinom` is the same as `\pi` as `\mathcal` has no effect on Greek.

Comment: Thanks and how to use something like Trebuchet font in math mode allowing these italics and bold greek letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments in the package detail the available fonts for each option, for `cm` that is

```
  % \sfdefault is cmss
  % no slanted bold letters
  % no slanted bold capital Greeks
```

so as no bold fonts are declared, `\bm` can not access them.

If you use `px` then the package documents

```
  % \sfdefault is pxss (pxfonts.sty)
  % slanted bold letters
  % slanted bold capital Greeks
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,hidelinks]{report}
       
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[px]{sfmath}

% no!! \newcommand{\pinom}{\hbox{$\mathcal{\pi}$}}

% \usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}  
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
% & \pinom = P (\vb*{\Theta}_\mathrm{M} | M \vb*{D}) \\ 
& \pi =P(\bm{\mathsl{\Theta}}_{\mathrm{M}}\mid M\bm{D})
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got an error
:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file rtxbsssl): Font rtxbsssl at 720 not found

==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: you have an incomplete installation the px fonts are in texlive and miktex, sorry I can't help with miktex specifics as I don't use it, but you should see pxfonts or newpx or some such in the miktex console @ElenaGreg

Comment: I have installed both packages, but it did not help

Comment: @ElenaGreg sorry I can't help with miktex installs, does it work with `tx` instead of `px` that also has the bold fonts.

Comment: I tried another computer with linux instead of windows and it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `sansmathfonts` package has outline bold italic math fonts based on Computer Modern Sans Serif:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,hidelinks]{report}
       
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}

\newcommand{\pinom}{\hbox{$\mathcal{\pi}$}}

\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{bm}  

\newcommand\mathbfit[1]{\bm{\mathit{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& \pinom = P (\mathbfit{\Theta}_\mathrm{M} | M \mathbfit{D}) \\ 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: sansmathfonts sample]

The `\vb*` command you used is package-specific and gets you bitmap fonts.  I defined a `\mathbfit` command instead.  This is the same syntax as `isomath` or `unicode-math`, two other packages you can use to get bold Italic mathematical Greek, so changing the fonts or copy-pasting into a new document should be easy.